# Youtube data API key stopped working. Getting accessNotConfigured error

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, api-key

We've been using a simple API key to fetch public Youtube videos through a in house developed Moodle plugin for a little over a year. Today, I realized this key no longer works while working on a new feature. Using the key in browser to make sure the problem is not from my code, I get an accessNotConfigured error. The key is only used to fetch public data from Youtube.

I tried all the solutions found here about regenerating the key and making sure there were no restrictions. Also note that this Youtube account was created just for the purpose of using this key and nobody logged into or changed anything for this account in over a year.

Something very strange I noticed is that my daily quota is at 0. When I tried to change it, it said "Enter a new quota limit between 0 and 0.". Bug?

Checking the history for the last 48h, there were 49 requests (all today) with a 100% error rate.

The Youtube Data API v3 has always been activated but for good measures, I also activated the other Youtube related APIs.

Error I get while trying this in-browser request: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=player&id=nl9q1qbDSHo&key=API_KEY

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project {ID} before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project={ID} then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project={ID}"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project {ID} before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project={ID} then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
 }
}
```

... and getting a false response from the PHP @file_get_contents() request (I stress, this has always worked until today).

Has anything changed very recently with this API that could be responsible for this new inexplicable behaviour? Fetching data from the API is / should be as straight forward as it gets. Not sure what else I could try.

Answer (score 1):

Never got this working again. Deleted/recreated new keys, deactivated/reactived APIs until my fingers bled.

Got it working again (day quota of 0 finally lifted) by deleting and recreating a new project from scratch, then new keys.

I want these wasted hours of my life back Google.